# What does ?{} mean in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

What does a `?{ }` block mean in a PowerShell?

For example

```
[enum]::GetValues([io.fileoptions]) | ?{$_.value__ -band 0x90000000}
```

Comment: `help ?` in powershell would have found this alias for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`?` is an alias for `Where-Object`. The curly brackets are used if you have to do something more complex with the actual object. You could also write:

```
[enum]::GetValues([io.fileoptions]) | Where-Object { $_.value__ -band 0x90000000}
```

Comment: I edtied my answer because `-band` is not available if you don't use the curly brackets.

Comment: PowerShell can be so terse with characters it is often a challenge to know the bits of syntax like this! I put together [The Complete Guide to PowerShell Punctuation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/the-complete-guide-to-powershell-punctuation/) to make it easy to decode any PowerShell from a one-page wallchart.

Answer (score 15):

Use [`Get-Alias` cmdlet](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293964) in doubts:

> **Description**
>
> The `Get-Alias` cmdlet gets the aliases (alternate names for commands and executable files) in the current session. This includes
>   built-in aliases, aliases that you have set or imported, and aliases
>   that you have added to your Windows PowerShell profile.
>
> By default, `Get-Alias` takes an alias and returns the command name. When you use the `Definition` parameter, `Get-Alias` takes a command name
>   and returns its aliases.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, `Get-Alias` displays non-hyphenated alias names in an "`<alias> -> <definition>`" format to
>   make it even easier to find the information that you need.

```
PS D:\PShell> Get-Alias ?

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName  
-----------     ----                                               ----------  
Alias           % -> ForEach-Object                                            
Alias           ? -> Where-Object                                              
Alias           h -> Get-History                                               
Alias           r -> Invoke-History
```

Answer (score 7):

**?** is an alias for Where-Object cmdlet, though it also has another alias - where.

**{}** curly brackets are used in case of script block, in this case it's a filter script block, it's mostly used for complex filtering, i.e. for more than one critera, like this:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -like '*audio*' -and $_.Status -eq 'Running'}
```